# Battlefield 3 ''Race''  in ME3 Multiplayer

Tags: mass-effect-3, mass-effect-3-multiplayer

In the ME3 multiplayer lobby, I've seen some people list Battlefield 3 instead as their race. How do you obtain this? Is there any other perks other than the name change?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to log in to Origin with an account that has an activated Battlefield 3 Online Pass, and the pack is only for the PC and Xbox 360 versions of ME3. From the [Mass Effect Wiki:](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Mass_Effect_3_Multiplayer#Store)

> Battlefield 3 Pack (Free, single-use) - Unlock your Battlefield 3 Limited Edition soldier! A kit containing items with an aesthetic inspired by Battlefield 3. Requires that the player signs in to Mass Effect 3 with an Origin account linked to a Battlefield 3 Online Pass. (PC and Xbox 360 only)

The Battlefield 3 "race" is mostly a Human Soldier with the power [Carnage](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Carnage_%28power%29) instead of Concussive Shot. [Full list of Powers at the Wiki](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Mass_Effect_3_Multiplayer#Class_and_Race), aside from the obvious cosmetic differences.

Answer (score -2):

I believe they must have changed or lifted those exclusives, because I have never played any Battlefield and I use a PS3, and I unlocked the Battlefield 3 soldier with a veteran pack yesterday.  I don't see what the big deal is -- it's kind of a mediocre class.